# Getting audio data as array from microphone

Tags: javascript, html, audio, webkitaudiocontext

I want to log audio data that i get from microphone:

```
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        var context = new AudioContext();
        var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ audio: true }, function (stream) {
            var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            source.connect(analyser);
            analyser.connect(context.destination);

            setInterval(function () {
                var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
                analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
                console.log(array);
            }, 1000);
        }, function () { });
```

I'm talking in microphone but logged array contains only 0 values every time. Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this will help http://jsfiddle.net/mmanrique/vynvu/ , https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/webrtc-integration.html . You might need to check the page has permission to access microphone.

Comment: I'm afraid your jsFiddle example needs fix: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://thelab.thingsinjars.com/web-audio-tutorial/hello.mp3. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Comment: how can i convert the audio in into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried in chrome canary and it works! Browser issue, hope they'll fix it soon

Comment: May I ask you, what the values in array mean? In my tests, they change fast and then become static after few seconds.